# Finding all MINIMUM values in a column in an Excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

Column D contains numerical value sets, each set is of random number of rows & each set is divided by a blank row. Need to highlight MINIMUM value in each set.

[image: sample sheet]

in the above image D4 & D7 needs to be highlighted

Comment: How about using formula to get the min result? You can remove RATE value in D1 and in E1 enter the formula: =IF(D1="",MIN(OFFSET(D2,,,MATCH("",D2:D10&"",),)),"") end with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. Then you will get the min result in E1 and E5.

Comment: Thanks phuclv, it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

*Since you have a typical data set (MFG and ITEM are unique) therefore, I would like to suggest create **H**elper Data to find `MINIMUM` value from each subset, to highlight them in `RATE` column.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter this formula in cell `O47` & fill it down.

  ```
  =IF($L47="Grp 1",MIN(N$47:N$49),IF($L47="Grp 2",MIN(N$51:N$55),IF($L47="Grp 3",MIN(N$57:N$60),"")))
  ```
- Select required data range in `RATE` column.
- Reach to **C**onditional Format then **N**ew Rule & use this formula.

  `=OR($N47=$O$47,$N47=$O$51,$N47=$O$57)`
- Apply an appropriate cell format and finish with Ok.

---

**N.B.**

- *For neatness later on you may hide the **H**elper data column (`Column O`).*

[image]

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: RATE column ranges are dynamic & often changes in number of rows as this report is derived vide PivotTable which derives live data. Also there are hundreds of ranges that are needed to be checked.

Comment: @PankajArora,, I've suggested a method based on the data you have shared with us,, now U r disclosing other facts,, better [Edit] your post add add all basic facts,, and please try to avoid day to day twist to the question,, since we are investing lot's of time to create a good answer!!

Comment: @PankajArora,, if you are ready to fill ITEM column with Product Name (like in B3, B4 Prod1, B7:B10 Prod 2) and so on then I can suggest you one improvised method, solves the issue & handling dynamic RATE range,, just confirm through comments or better EDIT you post with new Screen Shot !!